# OpenCV, projection on 3d surface

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, raspberry-pi3, projection, autonomy

I'm currently working on a school project with an "autonomous" car, I need to project the image from my camera (which is situated on the car and slightly tilted), onto a 2d surface representing a road (i assume the road is perfectly flat), **given the FOV, position and angle of my camera relative to the surface, how would I project it in OpenCV?**
What i need excatly is for the projection to be as if I had filmed the road from above at a 90° angle.
Thanks in advance for help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use opencv function to do it

```
C++: void reprojectImageTo3D(InputArray disparity, OutputArray _3dImage, InputArray Q, bool handleMissingValues=false, int ddepth=-1 )
```

The Q matrix is inverse of projection matrix K which contains camera center and fx fy

[image]

You can artificially create a disparity say a gradient map to represent the depth of the flat surface.

Then pass Q, disparty, and output3Dmat you want

The program will gives you what you want

Comment: Hehe, a bit late :) I did it kinda incorrectly using warpPerspective ( incorrect because further things are closer on y axis ) but it worked at the end :P, bit thanks a lot for your answer, I will remember it for the next time